# Can we install iPhone SDK 4 in iPhone OS 3

Tags: iphone

Can i install a iPhone4 SDK, where my Mac Book has only iPhone OS3? If it is possible will i get all the features of iPhone OS4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can update it. but do this only of you need features of new iOS 4 (multitask and so on). if you are don't i guess u colud stay on iOS 3

Answer (score 0):

All the new iOS4 APIs are included in iPhone SDK 4 so just download it and start developing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. please can u let me know the how to upgrade and install iPhone OS4 in my iPhone 3GS phone?

Comment: @Cathy Connect to iTunes, "search for updates", update, done... It's offically released now.

Comment: Can anyone download the iPhone OS4 or it is only who have registered in the developers program?

Comment: Plug it in to your computer, run iTunes, choose 'Check for Upgrade' from the 'Cathy's iPhone' status page.

Comment: It is free for everyone as of last Monday.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of iOS SDK 4.0 removes all SDK's before 3.2. However, you're still able to develop for your 3.0 devices.

- set Base SDK to 4.0
- set Deployment Target (Target -> Info -> Build : "iPhone OS Deployment Target" ) "to iPhone OS 3.0"

be aware of the fact that if you develop your app for 3.0, the use of API's oder Methods within API's only available from 4.0 onwards will crash your app.

the use of the "respondsToSelector" Method will let you know if a method is available on the current device that is executing your code.
This enables you to make use of the new API's if your app runs on a 4.0 device whilst maintaining "backwards"-compatibility for 3.0 (or whatever OS Version you set as Deployment Target"

`if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden: withAnimation:)])`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. please can u let me know the how to upgrade and install iPhone OS4 in my iPhone 3GS phone?

Comment: ok thats a simple one, open XCode then click Window->Organizer. connect your device, select your device from the "Devices Folder" within the Organizer. On the Right hand side you can select the Software-Version of the device.